# PhpStorm. Live Edit not working on Mac

Tags: macos, ide, phpstorm, liveedit

I have installed PhpStorm to my Mac. Then installed LiveEdit Plugin to it and JetBrains Extension to Chrome. I activate LiveEdit in `View -> Live Edit` and open it by `View -> Open in Browser.` In my case it opened at `http://localhost:63342/Markup/index.html`. I trying to make changes, but can see them only after page reloading. Live Editing not working. Help please! :)